# Remove grouping separator from a decimal number in Android

Tags: android, decimalformat

I have a decimal number that was formatted using DecimalFormat. When It was formatted I use  decimal.setGroupingUsed(true) because I needed.

Now I need to do the reverse method, that is, I have a number with integer decimals grouped like this 3,200.95 and I want to obtain 3200.95 (remove grouping symbol).

I do not want to replace "," with "" as grouping symbol depends on the country. Some countries it is "." and some others "," so I have tried to use DecimalFormat by setting grouping to false:

```
decimal.setGroupingUsed(false)
```

but then I do not know how to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: So what happens when you call `DecimalFormat.parse()`? Does it fail?

Comment: You could replace the **first** character that is either a `,` or a `.` with empty string, assuming those are the only two allowed separators

Comment: @ianhanniballake it parses 3,200.95 into 3

Comment: Why are you storing the Number as a String?  Just store it as a Number and then turn it into a String only to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want setGroupingUsed to be true, since you expect those symbols to be in the string you're parsing.  You'll use the parse method to turn that String into a Number.

Comment: My error was that I had set setGroupingUsed to false.... setting it to true and then parse the string into a number works like a charm! thanks!